# Fussion of two SQlite3 tables into new one with sum of value in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two SQLite3 tables in two separate sqlite files:

Table1 (in file1):

```
Id    Number       
----- ------
21    1 
22    2
23    3 
24    4
```

and Table2 (in file2):

```
Id    Number       
----- ------
21    15 
32    16
33    17 
34    18
```

I would like to produce a new table, which accumulates values of Number if there is match. So I would like an output:

TableSummary (should be in Newfile or in file1):

```
Id    Number       
----- ------
21    16
22    2
23    3 
24    4 
32    16
33    17 
34    18
```

What kind of statement I should use to achieve the result?

Comment: I forgot to mention that those tables are in two separate files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to combine both tables:

```
SELECT Id, Number FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Number FROM Table2
```

Then combine the duplicates by using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Number)
FROM (SELECT Id, Number FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Id, Number FROM Table2)
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: How to do it if the tables are in different files? The result table should be in one of the files or in a new one.